# How to deploy Python application using CGI on IIS?

Tags: python, iis, cgi

I am new to python and I try to deploy a simple hello python application on IIS and I followed this URL

https://support.sisense.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115007362727-Installing-Python-on-IIS

Hello.py

```
print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print '<html>'
print '<head>'
print '<title>Hello Word - First CGI Program</title>'
print '</head>'
print '<body>'
print '<h2>Hello Word! This is my first CGI program</h2>'
print '</body>'
print '</html>'
```

However, it error's as mentioned below

```
HTTP Error 401.3 - Unauthorized
You do not have permission to view this directory or page because of the access control list (ACL) configuration or encryption settings for this resource on the Web server
```

I feel the issue may not be related to permission **as I am able to browse hello.html**

I tried some of the solutions provided in SO to resolve the issue but nothing worked.  Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To configure Python with IIS you can try to follow the below steps:

1. Download the latest Python version because IIS will not work with the python old version.

https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/

2. Below is the `hello.py` file:

```py
print("Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n")
print('<html>')
print('<head>')
print('<title>Hello Word - First CGI Program</title>')
print('</head>')
print('<body>')
print('<h2>Hello Word! This is my first CGI program</h2>')
print('</body>')
print('</html>')
```

3. Enable IIS CGI feature.

[image]

4. Open IIS Manager. Right-click on the server name and select add site.

[image]

5. Add site binding detail folder path (python folder)

[image]

6. Select a site and click on the handler mapping from the middle pane.

[image]

7. Click on add script map from the action pane.

[image]

8. Add script mapping value.

`*.py`, and map it to `c:\Python37-32\python.exe %s %s`.

[image]

[image]

Make sure directory browsing is enabled.

[image]

`web.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="python" path="*.py" verb="*" modules="CgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Python37-32\python.exe %s %s" resourceType="File" />
        </handlers>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Set `iis_iusrs` and `iusr` permission to the site folder(`c:\pythonapp`) and python folder(`C:\Python37-32`).
Make sure anonymous authentication is enabled, and the application pool is set to the application pool identity.
After making all the changes restart IIS server and browse the site.

[image]